# Jquery UI Sortable : Change <li> in <ul> if out of <ul>

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have items sortable which are connected between the different `ul`.

I would like to have the possibility to drop the `li` outside a `ul` and therefore transform the `li` into a `ul`.

**Here my code:**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( ".drop" ).sortable({
            connectWith: ".drop",
        });

        $( ".sortable" ).sortable({
            items: '.drop',
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="sortable">
    <ul id="sortable1" class='drop'>
        <li class="ui-state">Item 1</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="sortable2" class='drop'>
        <li class="ui-state">Item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state">Item 2</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="sortable3" class='drop'></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please try and clarify your question?  I'm having trouble understanding what you want.

Comment: Just done :) Is it more clear ?

Comment: I may found a solution
this : nestedSortable jQuery Plugin
But not tried. I'll let you know

Comment: There is no `lu` tag, so no, it hasn't helped.

Comment: OMG i'm so sorry, it's not lu but "ul"... Shame...
NestedSortable is the solution I found